# Why in a PMOS transistor VDS has to be negative?

Tags: voltage, transistors, pmos

I can't understand why it is required that VDS is negative in a PMOS transistor while it must be positive in an NMOS.

Thanks

Comment: If Vds is positive, the body diode conducts.

Comment: @BrianDrummond This is true if the body is permanently connected to the source, but for a 4-terminal PMOSFET that problem will not determine which terminal is the source. For a 4-terminal PMOS, the source is the terminal with the higher voltage at any given instant.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is as simple as it gets: if voltage between drain and source is 2V, voltage between source and drain is -2V. It's exactly the same thing, just in the opposite direction.

In NMOS, the conventional current flows from drain to source. Thus you need to have positive Vds.

In PMOS, the conventional current froms from source to drain. But you measure Vds as voltage between DRAIN and SOURCE. Since you need Source-Drain voltage positive, Drain-Source will be negative.

Exactly the same logic applies to Vgs. Basically, Vab means Va-Vb.

Comment: This is the correct answer. For a PMOS transistor in its purest form, with 4 terminals, the source is never at a lower voltage than the drain...the terminal with the higher voltage is the source **by definition**.

Answer (score 1):

\$V_{DS}\$ can be positive in a PMOS device but the problem is that the body diode internal to the MOSFET will start conducting and so it won't operate effectively as a switch. Here is a picture that shows the body diode in an NMOS and PMOS device: -

[image]

If you can source a MOSFET where the body diode is not connected to the source terminal then you can use them for bi-directional switching as is done inside a transmission gate: -

[image]

In the above diagram the body diode in the PMOS is connected to \$V_{DD}\$ and for the NMOS connected to GND.

Comment: I don't think you really answered the question for the 4-terminal PMOS device. If the body is connected to Vdd and the transistor is used as a pass transistor, can the source voltage be lower than the drain? No, because the terminal with higher voltage is **defined** to be the source at any given instant.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson you seem to redefining the question.

Comment: I don't think so. Looking at the PMOS pass transistor, why must VDS be negative? Your first sentence is true for PMOSFETs where the body has been permanently connected to one of the terminals...that terminal must be the source. But for a 4-terminal MOSFET used as a pass transistor...even a bidirectional pass transistor...it is still true that VDS must be negative. And the reason is that the terminal with the higher voltage is, by definition, the source for a PMOS transistor.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I'm not sure which part of my answer you think I define the source in an analogue gate - I'm struggling to follow what you see as wrong.

Comment: It's that you **don't** define the source in a pass transistor, so you don't explain why it must be true that Vds is negative. I didn't say that you were **wrong** but that you didn't quite get to the final answer.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson but you've already said that the source is defined as the one with the higher voltage - I didn't go down this route in my answer because, as far as I can tell, the OP probably wouldn't want any more information other than what is vital.